# Display data from a database without specifying columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, authentication

I have a simple login page. What I want to do is when the login is correct, I want to display all columns - I don't want to manually specify which columns to show in the while loop.

This is a sample I have in C# using SQL Server 2008 express:

```
private void Authenticate(string userName, string password)
{
    string connString = "server=.\\sqlexpress; database=TestDatabase; trusted_connection=true";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();

    string sqlCommand = "select * from Registration where UserName='" + userName + "' and   Password='" + password + "'";
    SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = sqlCommand;

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();          

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        lblResult.Text += reader["CourseId"] + " " + reader["CourseName"] + " " + reader["Instructor"] + "<br />";
    }
```

}

I know this is not the best implementation.

How can I fill lblResult with everything that is returned from the Registration table?

Comment: LINQ + DataSource perhaps?

Comment: you can access the reader[] by it's Ordinal position

Comment: where UserName='" + userName + "'  --- Really ?? Google SqlParameters

Comment: Your current implementation is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks! Please read this MSDN article on the subject: [SQL Injection] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx)

Comment: @Alexander How would you change the code to avoid SQL Injection attacks ?

Comment: Here's a quick overview that should help you get up to speed on using SqlParameter's: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter As Scott Selby suggested, you should change the code to use SqlParameter's instead of concatenating strings to be passed on as queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024); /* arbitrary size */
while (reader.read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(reader.GetName(i));
        sb.Append(": ");
        sb.Append(reader[i]);
    }
    sb.Append("<br />");
}
lblResult.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Something like that, based on the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

A [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) has a property called `FieldCount` that tells you how many fields were returned, then you just iterate through the Items index with that knowledge. I would also use a `StringBuilder` to build the resultant string, instead of concatenating strings to give us a performance boost. Something like this:

```
var str = new StringBuilder()
while (reader.Read())
{
    for(int i=0; i<reader.FieldCount ; i++)
    {
        str.Append(reader[i].ToString());
        str.Append(" ");
    }
    str.Append("<br/>");    
}
lblResult.Text = str.ToString();
```